# Pandas, how do I filter multiple values in a column?

Tags: python, pandas

Sorry I'm a newbie at this, but I'm trying to filter a dataframe based on the the values within one column. I have a set of usernames and I want to filter usernames with:

1.duplicate usernames

2.usernames with the following special characters: [ : ; | = , + * ? < >

3.excess spaces within usernames (ex. "john    doe  ")

I'm not sure how to set parameters or how to even get started.

Comment: Not a duplicate at all. The question is about different technics of selection.

Comment: Ideally you should have googled and find the answer easily. However, you can take following code snippet


    import pandas as pd
    import re

    def regex_filter(val):
        regex = re.compile('[:;|=,+*?<>')
        if val:
            mo = re.search(regex,val)
            if mo:
                return False
            else:
                return True
        else:
            return True


    df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
    df_filtered = df[df['user_id'].apply(regex_filter)]

Comment: Not able to add this as code. you can copy code and use

Comment: check out all the available `str` methods in pandas: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/series.html#api-series-str